# how can I use a sproc @param as column alias?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can use a sproc param as a column alias? For example:

```
SELECT '12345' AS @MySprocParam
```

I tried the following sql but it doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @MySprocParam VARCHAR(50) = 'TestAlias'
SELECT 'ASDF' AS @MyProcParam
```

Answer (score 2):

You need dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @MySprocParam VARCHAR(50) = 'TestAlias'

SET @MyProcParam = QUOTENAME(@MyProcParam)

exec( 'SELECT ''ASDF'' AS '+@MyProcParam)
```

Comment: I wish there was a more simple and less intrusive way to do that

Comment: @user6867266 - you can use `Quotename` to avoid intrusion here. But it is impossible to avoid dynamic sql